# Constant latency for any function?

Tags: verilog

In some online verilog compilers(which I'm using to learn Verilog) I'm trying to write a module with state variables. When module is given a work-id and two numbers other than zero, the result is written to another variable.

When I change function from

```
c=a**b
```

to

```
c=(a**b+a**(b+1)+(a+1)**b)/10;
```

it gives result after same number of clock cycles. How can these two functions complete at same clock cycles?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_verilog_online.php

```
module pow;
parameter rdy=0,bsy=1;
    reg [63:0] a;
    reg [63:0] b;
    reg [63:0] c;
    reg [63:0] work_id_input;
    reg [63:0] work_id_output;
    reg [3:0] state;

    initial
        begin
            state=rdy;
            work_id_input=0;
            work_id_output=0;
            a=0;
            b=0;
            c=0;
        end


        always
        #1 begin
            if(state==rdy && a>0 && b>0 && work_id_input!=work_id_output)
            begin
                state=bsy;
            end
        end

        always
        #1 begin
            if(state==bsy && work_id_input==work_id_output)
            begin
                state=rdy;
            end
        end


        always
            #1 begin
            if(state==bsy)
                begin
                 c=(a**b+a**(b+1)+(a+1)**b)/10;
                 a=0;
                 b=0;
                 work_id_output=work_id_input;
                end
            end
endmodule


module main;
reg [63:0] time_;
reg [63:0] ctr;

pow pow1();

  initial 
    begin
      ctr=0;
      #100 $finish ;
    end

    always
    #1 begin
        ctr=ctr+1;
        if(pow1.state==pow1.rdy && pow1.work_id_output == pow1.work_id_input)
        begin
            pow1.work_id_input<=ctr;
            pow1.a<=ctr;
            pow1.b<=3;
        end
    end

    always
    #1 begin
        $display("%g  counter=%d  result=%d  input_id=%d output_id=%d",$time,ctr, pow1.c,pow1.work_id_input,pow1.work_id_output);
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: This is how hardware works. These two functions will complete in exact the same amount of clock cycles, but maximum clock frequencies and logic elements usage will be totally different.

Comment: Do you mean, these two needs different counters/clocks if they are to be used in same cpu so they dont lower whole cpu frequency?

Comment: How do I set proper clock for these? I dont know how much delay or latency will be there per step.

Answer (score 2):

Verilog HDL is a Hardware Description Language, so the constructs can turn out into synthesizable hardware.

Here, both the above samples gets converted to **combinational circuits**. By *intuition*, we can see `c=a**b` will have lesser hardware than `c=(a**b+a**(b+1)+(a+1)**b)/10`. But the point here is there is *no* sequential logic involved.

Combinational circuits have no clock dependency, ideally, all that you apply as inputs can be converted to outputs instantaneously within zero **simulation time**. Hence the simulator provides result at the same time.

But, in **real hardware**, due to finite setup & hold time and other gate delays, some time is required to convert the applied inputs to outputs. Here, the second sample may require more hardware and hence it can handle low frequency inputs as compared to the first one. In this respect, they differ in the frequency of operation.

Here, this has nothing to do with the **value** of `ctr`, but it has a lot to do with the **rate of change** of `ctr` that the actual circuit can handle.

All that makes the difference here is after you synthesize the code (or you manually add some gate delays here). For more information about synthesis, [this](http://guabiruba.sc.gov.br%E2%80%BAEmbeddedProgram) book can be helpful.

Comment: How do I make async(with different clocked) modules contacting on a common interface such that I can compare performance of independent modules? (as a "producer - consumer problem" where modules consume and main module produce)

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your comment. Do you want to connect a test fixture with some inputs to the module. Or you want to connect these two different design modules. Moreover, since the current code is not synthesizable, you can use `posedge clk` and `reset` signal to do so. You cannot see the difference just by **simulating** both the designs. Performance analysis must be performed for that.

Comment: I was going to test how many "add" operations could be made(in a module) while a single "divide" operation is being computed(in another module). But now I can see they run at the sametime so adder units will be idle waiting for division and this is not a producer/consumer style operation.